# jquery find and replace

Tags: jquery, replace, preg-replace

Here is my string.

```
<div id='content'>here is my text {{ and some more }}</div>
```

I want to replace all {{ with < pre > tags and }} with < /pre > tags.

so the string would output like this.

```
<div id='content'>here is my text <pre> and some more </pre></div>
```

i need to do this using jquery. i have got so far.

```
var textarea=$('#content').text();
$(".addesc1").text(textarea).html().replace(/{{/g, "<pre>");
```

whats the best function to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some thing simple like:

```
var textarea=$('#content'); 
textarea.html(textarea.html().replace("{{","<pre>")).html(textarea.html().replace("}}","</pre>"));
```

as illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/psSwE/

This says "Take my jQuery object "textarea" and replace the "{{" and then take that result set and replace the "}}".

I WOULD suggest changing the name of your variable however as "var textarea" just might confuse future developers (make them pause to think is not good).

EDIT: Note that the use of the jQuery "chaining" is one of the cool things about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".addesc1").text(
    $('#content').text().replace(/{{/g, "<pre>").replace(/}}/g, "</pre>")
);
```

Comment: this is not really good if you need to use `{{` within your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using regex, which is kind of an over kill here.

I suggest :

```
txt.split('{{').join('<pre>');
```

Then, using jQuery, you can replace the content of an object like that :

```
var myobject = $('selector');
myobject.html(myobject.html().split('{{').join('<pre>'));
```

Comment: Agreed on the regex, why pull that in if you don't have to.

Comment: This is a bonus on a general good practice. As long as the answer is in the post too, I don't see any problem with that.